# How to run code when a certain character is recieved in c#

Tags: c#, string, server, tcp, client

so I have a c# program in which I am trying to run a certain code in a client when a certain character is recieved from the server. What is supposed to happen, If the server sends g to the client it's supposed to run certain code, and while then client and server do connect and they do acknowledge g was sent and received, the code in the if then statement does not run. Here is the client code where when receiving g it is supposed to run code on the client:
byte[] bb = new byte[100];

```
            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);



            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)

                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(bb));



          



            string atk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb);

            MessageBox.Show("Recieved Command " + atk);



            if (atk == "g")

            {

                MessageBox.Show("information received.);

                search.RunWorkerAsync();

            }
```

The g is recieved from the server no problem, but the code does not run. I am wondering why this might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you change the message box to `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine` and show the output please.

All so your provide your full **Callback** as some code is missing

But maybe don't convert

```
string atk = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb);
```

if you know the letter "g" in **ASCII:** is "**103**" in **HEX:** 67
do a direct compare without convert it to string

```
if(bb == 103)
{
    MessageBox.Show("information received.);
    search.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi, well when running it as in a terminal window it says System.Byte [] in CMD and that's it. Using your code it simply says that a string cannot be converted to a byte? Thanks.

Comment: Whats odd is that a messagebox shows the received character no problem.

Comment: Also I tried converting it to hex and this did not fix the problem
 Thanks